# Jasmine - Wait Async library to load completely before performing tests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine

My project contains an external library that use async XMLHttpRequest to load data. The loading time can vary between 200ms to 10000ms.

I would like Jasmine to perform the tests only when that library has finished loading.

I am a little bit confuse with the Async testing in Jasmine. I would like to have only one timeout that will wait beforeAll tests, then perform each test synchronously.

Is it possible? I have something like below, but it's not working.

```
describe("External library cartovista", function() {
    beforeAll(function(done){
        var cartovista = window.cartovista;
        done();
    }, 10000);

    it("cartovista should be loaded", function(done) {
         expect(cartovista).toBeDefined();
         done();
    });

    it("cartovista component and data working as wanted", function(done) {
        //an example of testing over the data
        var data = cartovista.data[0]
        expect(cartovista.afunction(data)).toBe(true);
        done();
    });

    //etc...
});
```

**Edit: I have to mention that I want to perform the tests with the real data.**

Comment: You can try to create mock for XMLHttpRequest then you will not need to wait for the request.

Comment: I have to mention that I want to perform tests with the real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do what I am trying to do. I was pretty close to a correct answer in my question.

**Note that the `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` should be greater than the `setTimeout` interval**

```
describe("External library cartovista", function() {

    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 11000;

    var cartovista;

    beforeAll(function(done){
        setTimeout(function() {   
            cartovista = window.cartovista;
            done();
        }, 10000);
    });

    it("cartovista should be loaded", function() {
         expect(cartovista).toBeDefined();
    });

    it("cartovista component and data working as wanted", function() {
        //an example of testing over the data
        var data = cartovista.data[0]
        expect(cartovista.afunction(data)).toBe(true);
    });

    //etc...
});
```

[See Jasmine doc](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)